# how to add new azure function via maven plugin at intellij IDE

Tags: java, azure, maven, intellij-idea, azure-functions

I want to use timerTrigger in azure functions. 
I created function according this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij
it is generated by default httpTrigger. I tried command of `azure-functions:add`. 
I succeeded adding timerTrigger but I encountered with a lot of errors

How I can delete httpTrigger and declaring only timerTrigger? 
before I run the `azure-functions:add`:

[image]

after running the command:

[image]

I guess it is related to azure plugin and maven plugin conflict but not sure and I don't know how to handle such this situation

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I suppose it doesn't support create java function with default timer trigger. However you could delete the HTTP one then create the timer, cause you don't provide much information so maybe you could refer to my steps.

1. Create the function with maven.(I'm using the 1.22 version)
2. Delete the HTTP function, and delete the test folder.

   [image]
3. Create the Timer Trigger function.
   After this the project will be like this.**(Before packaging remember set the storage connection string in the `local.settings.json`)**

   [image]
4. Package it.(**Use the package method in the Lifecycle**.)

   [image]
5. Run it with `azure-functions:run` under azure-functions plugin.

   [image]